# #python passing list items into function

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

trying to pass list items(PreCalc) into a simple function. trying to covert the list into a tuple version (calc) and then call the function.

Get the error message: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

How can I pass my inputs() into the function?

```
def calc(x,y,z):
a = x * (1 + (y/100))
b = a * (1 - (z/100))
c = (b / 12)
d = x * (1 - (z/100)) / 12
print("the annual gross salary is %.2f" %(x),"kEUR")
print("the annual bonus opportunity is %.2f" %(y), "%")
print("the annual gross salary plus bonus is %.2f" %(a), "kEUR")
print("you have to pay around %.2f" %(z),"% in tax")
print("the annual net salary incl. bonus is %.2f" %(b),"kEUR")
print("The average monthly post-tax salary incl. bonus is %.2f" %(c),"kEUR")
print("The average monthly post-tax salary excl. bonus is %.2f" %(d),"kEUR")

PreCalc = [0,0,0]
PreCalc[0] = int(input("please enter your annual gross salary"))
PreCalc[1] = int(input("please enter your bonus opportunity in %"))
PreCalc[2] = int(input("please enter your tax rate in %"))
print(PreCalc)
calc = tuple(PreCalc)
print(calc)
calc()
```

Comment: You can't use the same name `calc` for the function and a variable.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: You've rebound the name `calc` to the tuple, shadowing the `calc` function. Pick different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert your list into a tuple

```
calc(*PreCalc)
```

and as the comments say don't shadow the calc function.

You also don't need use a list, you can do this instead.

```
x = int(input("please enter your annual gross salary"))
y = int(input("please enter your bonus opportunity in %"))
z = int(input("please enter your tax rate in %"))
calc(x, y, z)
```

Comment: wow - thanks for the quick answers - works great - thanks for helping a super newbie here.